# Building React Native for iOS fails: code signature not vaild for AppAuth

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, appauth

I am trying to integrate react-native-app-auth into my React Native app. It works on Android, but when trying to build the project on iOS I get the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/MapMobileWorkbench
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/38019FA7-8A4E-43F9-93BE-51A59E42308B/MapMobileWorkbench.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

After that pops up, continuing the run the app causes it to crash.

React Native Info:

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.6
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
      Memory: 1.29 GB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.16.1 - /var/folders/2p/5xwrclh55wjc5glqmnwdcbqm0000gp/T/yarn--1582121305976-0.1309360786018443/node
      Yarn: 1.22.0 - /var/folders/2p/5xwrclh55wjc5glqmnwdcbqm0000gp/T/yarn--1582121305976-0.1309360786018443/yarn
      npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.1/bin/npm
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.5 => 0.59.5
```

Both the .a library and the .framework for AppAuth are in the link list for the target I am building, but the color of the icon for the .framework file is more of a pale yellow versus the regular yellow of the rest of the .framework files linked. That is the only thing I have noticed that might mean something. I have tried deleting and reinstalling my pods a number of times without any luck there, either. And I have tried both the new and the legacy build systems. I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

mark the frameworks as (Do Not Embed) in the `Frameworks, Libraries and embedded content` section and in Build `Phases/Link Binary With Libraries`, Mark the frameworks as (optional). This should avoid the error.

Comment: I went through your solution for all of my third-party libraries (I got the same error for each), but now I am getting a new error: "You must override the `supportedEvents` method" which seems to be coming from RCTNativeAnimatedModule. I am not sure if this is caused by what I did for this solution or if it is a new error that just came up after solving this one.